# Problems installing matplot library for Python on Windows7

Tags: python, matplotlib, freetype

This is the situation:

I need to install matplotlib for my project.

Initially it told me it needed vcvarsall.bat, which I installed MS C++ 2008 for.
Then I tried to install it again and it is now giving me the following

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API-DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 "-IC:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I. "-IC:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\freetype2" -I.\freetype2 "-IC:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\python\include" "-I  C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\python\PC" /Tpsrc/ft2font.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6\Release\src/ft2font.obj
>
> ft2font.cpp
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>
> c:\users\name\downloads\matplotlib-1.1.0\src\ft2font.h(16) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
>
> error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

I tried to install freetyp2 and I ran an executable available for FreeType and it installed freetype in C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\include, however it still is giving me the error above. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to fix it?

Thank you for any help provided.
-Stan

I am using python to try to install this stuff.

Comment: Are you trying to install from source ?, which installer are you using? Matplotlib installs in win7 from binary installers with no hassle at all

Comment: D'oh you're right I was using the wrong isntaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want matplotlib (and don't care about a setting up a build environment for compiling components), the simplest solution is to install a pre-built verison of matplotlib.

The [pythonxy](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) project provides a python distribution that includes a large number of popular packages (including matplotlib).

Alternatively, you can download an installer directly from the [matplotlib project](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: pythonxy is the way to go on Windows. How ever, as someone wrote somewhere, if you have a picaso picture would you put in the toilet ? Using Debian and python is easier ;-)

Comment: It doesn't have GTK support though, which unfortunately is needed by the project I'm trying to build.